# Precise and fast timer in .Net

Tags: vb.net, timer, precision

I want to create a program using VB.Net which plays a sound (lets says a system beep, or a 100 millisecond-long wav file) every 200 milliseconds, with high precision. I tried .Net's Timer but it is not accurate and the beeps don't sound in equal time separation. I also tried CreateTimerQueueTimer from the kernel32.dll but still had the same problem.

Is there a more accurate timer that I can use to call a function on a set interval? Again, the emphasis is on precision.

Comment: Can you show me how to do that? Here is the code I have right now:

http://pastebin.com/nbhmsS82

the beeper thread calls a new beep thread every 100 milliseconds.

Comment: Too lazy. But there should be several duplicate questions.

Comment: Stopwatch is a more accurate timer but not sure if you can use if for duration and sleep.

Comment: Here is with StopWatch: http://pastebin.com/SneB92m1

It is still inprecise

Comment: QueryPerformanceCounter(aka Stopwatch) can measure intervals with high precision, but you can only take advantage of that with a spin-wait, and that's a bad idea. So you need to go with `timeBeginPeriod`.

Comment: Can you show me an example of how it is used in VB.net or C#.net?

Comment: I also found this but I don't know how to actually use it:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5501/The-Multimedia-Timer-for-the-NET-Framework